# How to disable default website for server when subdomain is not found?

Tags: apache, redirect, subdomain, webmin

I have multiple websites hosted on server using Webmin panel version 1.660

If I enter existing subdomain like www.domain2.com everything works fine, but for non-existing subdomains like wwwa.domain2.com server loads page from domain1.com

Is there any way to disable this feature?

I would like that non-existing subdomains would show 404 error or would be redirected to appropriate domain.

Comment: how is www.domain2.com a subdomain? subdomains should be *www.abc.domain2.com*

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache, search Google for 404 redirects and url rewriting. Also if you want to take it future, then you also need to configure your DNS to catch all subdomains and redirect to your HTTP server